# What are the units of the values in an autocovariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix A, which is m columns by n rows.  m contains the x, y, and z components of velocity data.  The rows show how these coordinates evolve with time.

When I calculate the autocovariance matrix with A^T*A, what are the units for each entry in the new matrix?  Is it the square of what the units are originally?  So, if I had m/s as my units originally, would they be (m/s)^2 in the covariance matrix?

I'm not exactly sure how the matrix multiplication works in this case, which is why I'm not sure what the units may be.

Thank you.

Comment: that should be correct.